# How to add headings to the different parts in a List of Figures/Tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

My current List of Figures looks like this -
[image]

I want to add the heading **S No** at the top of the numbers, **Name** at the top of the captions and **Page No:** at the top of the page numbers column. Also, I want to remove the periods. I am using the following packages -

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,fullpage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addto\captionsenglish{%
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{}}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}

\listoffigures
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution writes the "header" using `\addtocontents`.  Getting rid of the dots was slightly harder.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,fullpage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addto\captionsenglish{%
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{}}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure[2]{% remove dots (based on \l@chapter
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{2.5em}%originally 1.5em
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hrule
\listoffigures

\addtocontents{lof}{\string\contentsline {figure}{\string\numberline{\string\textbf{S No}}%
  {\string\textbf{Name}}}{\string\llap{\string\textbf{Page No}}}}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{test 1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

With package `tocloft`

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftafterloftitle{Sl No. \hfill Figure Caption \hfill Page No.}
```

or without `tocloft`

```
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of figures \vspace*{1pc}\newline Sl No. \hfill Name \hfill Page No.}
```

I am very sure, there will be a better way to do this.